# How to extract certain string out of long url kind of string in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

How to use regex in pandas to extract below field. the below is one of my pandas dataframe column value, but i wanted to only extract 'eastus' and keep it as value for this field. how to filter this. this position is always fixed

Sample df:

```
                          correlationId                                                 id                                                                level   ...      status.value status.localizedValue            tag
0    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/locations/eastus/events/xxxxxxxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxxxxx  Informational  ...    Succeeded             Succeeded  Managed by IT
```

command i tried:

```
if not df.empty:
        columns = ["correlationId","eventName.value","id","resourceGroupName","resourceProviderName.value","operationName.value","status.value","eventTimestamp","submissionTimestamp"]        
        df.columns = df.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())
        #print(df.columns)    
        df.fillna('Missing', inplace=True)
        drop_these = ['correlationId']
        df['Location'] = df.id.str.split("/")[8]
```

but its not working

Error:

```
 df['Location'] = df.id.split("/")[8]
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

any suggestion please

Comment: please share a sample of the dataframe, you are trying to set one value to the whole dataframe, is that what you are trying to achieve ? also what do you mean by not working ? what is happening exactly ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As it is, it should work. So maybe is a problem with your dataframe

Comment: shall updates with some sample data shortly my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id = '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/' \
     'locations/eastus/events/xxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxx'
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sample':[id]
})
df['Location'] = df['sample'].str.split("/",expand=True)[8]

print(df)
    sample                                                            Location
0  /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/locations/eastus/events/xxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxx   eastus
```